# How to invert logic on recursive calls?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

How to invert logic on recursive calls?

I have this solve that counts the number of recursive calls. It's working properly. But how can I invert the logic to count number

Comment: Simply change `if (digit == k)` by `if (digit != k)` and it does the job. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJue93

Comment: I don't see any code.  I'm not sure how @McNets or the answer below came up with suggestions.  Can you show your code and ask your question in relation to your code.  What does "invert logic" mean in this context?  Is this a simple recursion (calculating factorial recursively) or something more complex?

Comment: Wait a second, you removed all your code in an edit.  Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can simply invert a statement using `!` so it would be `!=` instead of `==`

Comment: When I invert, the result is different. can you help me?

Comment: If you could add a more clear code example, I could and will most definitely